# Show image just uploaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I let the user upload an image, which works fine. The image is also shown on the web form if the user loads the page for the first time.

The problem is when the user uploads another image (replacing the image) I want the new image to be shown on the page (using ajax), but nothing is shown.

the webform:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVllID" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Image ID="imgUploaded" runat="server" /><br />
```

server side script:

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)

    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'initieren
    txtVllID.Text = Nothing
    txtVllID.Text = Request.QueryString("vllid")
    imgUploaded.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?vllid=" & txtVllID.Text

End Sub
```

ImageHandler.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="ImageHandler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO

Public Class ImageHandler : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim vllid = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("vllid")
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    context.Response.WriteFile("App_Themes/theme_yellow/uploads/" + vllid + ".jpg")
End Sub


Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var settings = {
        url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx?vllid=" + $("#txtVllID").val(),
        allowedTypes: "jpg,jpeg,png,gif",
        onSuccess: function (files, response, xhr) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ImageHandler.ashx?vllid=" + $("#txtVllID").val(),
                datatype: "image/jpg",
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data); you see imagedata?(bytes?)
                    $("#imgUploaded").attr("src", data);
                }
            });
            $("#divGelukt").show("slow", function () { });
        }
    }
    $("#UploadArea").uploadFile(settings);
});
</script>
```

On the screen the image is not visible. When I look at the result code in the browser the imgUploades.src contains unreadable characters. How can I let this be shown as an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the img src to the image url, instead of downloading it with ajax.

```
    onSuccess: function (files, response, xhr) {
        $("#imgUploaded").attr("src", "ImageHandler.ashx?vllid=" + $("#txtVllID").val());
        $("#divGelukt").show("slow", function () { });
    }
```